# AirConsole on phone not working for dev?

Tags: airconsole

Whenever I boot up AirConsole either in Unity3D, the simulator, or a normal WebGL build in AirConsole, I can never connect my phone. It always shows the black loading screen but never actually loads while the simulated phones always work. It doesn't work both when I am connected to my home network and when I am not. How could I fix this?

I am using Unity 5.3.5 and the latest AirConsole plugin.

Thanks,
Mike S.

Answer (score 1):

From http://developers.airconsole.com/#/help

Make sure your controller.html is accessible from your phone.

Let's assume you are running your local web server on http://192.168.0.2:8080/

Try to access http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html using a normal web browser on the device that doesn't work. It should display the controller html.

If you can't access http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html from your phone, but from your computer, make sure you are in the same network and that your router does not have "Client Isolation" activated.

If you are testing with real smartphones, make sure you do not use http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/, because localhost is not your computer on the phone but the phone itself!