# Test with my own smartphone using Unity3d plugin

Tags: airconsole

I'm developing a game using Unity3D and I have a question about controllers. I set the "Browser start mode" as "Normal", then the airconsole web is opened properly but when I put the code into my smartphone, just a "loading" screen is shown (in the smartphone screen I mean).

I don't if it's due my custom controller is in my computer, not on my smartphone but...  any way to do that??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this from the FAQ at http://developers.airconsole.com:

> I can't load my game in the simulator or on a test phone!
>
> Make sure your screen.html and controller.html are accessible from all
>   devices. Let's assume you are running your local web server on
>   http://192.168.0.2:8080/ Try to access
>   http://192.168.0.2:8080/screen.html and
>   http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html using a normal web browser on
>   the device that doesn't work. It should display the screen/controller
>   html. If you can't access http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html from
>   your phone, but from your computer, make sure you are in the same
>   network and that your router does not have "Client Isolation"
>   activated. If you are testing with real smartphones, make sure you do
>   not use http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/, because localhost is
>   not your computer on the phone but the phone itself!

And these stack overflow links:

[AirConsole on phone not working for dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380981/airconsole-on-phone-not-working-for-dev)

[AirConsole phone controller screen not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890806/airconsole-phone-controller-screen-not-loading)